# Pluralization synonym request: [repositories]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Can we please synonymize [repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repositories) into [repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repository)?

- [repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repository) 4496 questions
- [repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repositories) 246 questions

Obvious pluralization, needs no explanation.